# How to implement expandable menu for NavigationView in Android

Tags: android, android-design-library

I was wondering if it is possible to implement an expandable menu for NavigationView like we would use with expandable ListView. Right now i am just clueless where to even start.

Comment: The answer is here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32664433/1074998

Comment: that seems promising although my requirement has changed but i will try it.

Answer (score 2):

The NavigationView is purposely limited, so it it likely difficult to customize it in the way you are asking (but not impossible, as anything can be done with enough effort and hacking).

The limited nature of the NavigationView is by design - it is supposed to be the main navigation control for your app, and be very simple.  You shouldn't try to customize it in the way you are asking, and instead see if you can fit your navigation into the existing model.

This is designed to be hard to customize, so you will keep it standard (and your app will stay consistent to Material Design standards).

Bottom line, see if you can fit into the existing model, instead of trying to customize it (and thus be non-standard).

Comment: The expandable nature is client requirement so i am stuck there.

Comment: Either talk to the client, or use something other then the NavView (ie. SlidingMenu library).  Sometimes in Android - if it is difficult to do - there is a reason (and you shouldn't do it).

Comment: I wanted to use the NavigationView, I think i have to be content using the old expadable list view.

Comment: If you listen to the "Android Developers Backstage" podcast about the Support libs - they discuss why they limited the design of the NavigationView (because this is supposed to be for nagivations, which tends to get over-complicated if left un-checked)