# How to add menu and submenu in NavigationView dynamic in android

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I want to add custom menu in slide navigation with menu icon as well as sub menu dynamically.Below code add menu successfully but sub menu is showing when slide navigation appear as well as unable to add icon to the menu so please help me to hide sub menu and show only menu with icon and when I click on menu then only its sub menu should be appear.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getId();

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Add menu dynamically
        Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
        SubMenu topChannelMenu = m.addSubMenu("Top Channels");

        // Add submenu.
        topChannelMenu.add("Foo");
        topChannelMenu.add("Bar");
        topChannelMenu.add("Baz");

        topChannelMenu = m.addSubMenu("Top Channels2");
        topChannelMenu.add("Foo2");
        topChannelMenu.add("Bar2");
        topChannelMenu.add("Baz2");


        MenuItem mi = m.getItem(m.size()-1);
        mi.setTitle(mi.getTitle());
    }

    private void getId()
    {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera)
        {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)
        {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow)
        {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage)
        {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share)
        {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send)
        {

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `Try this:
for(...){
MenuItem item = menu.add(...)
item.setIcon(...)
}`

Comment: Thank you so much  Pramod for help to add icon to menu. It is working.

Comment: Could you please know me one more thing, how to add sub menu and sub menu should be hide and when I click to menu then sub menu should be appear.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are looking for something that can expand. I suggest you to use expandable listview with navigationview. Because click event for expand ll be easier to manage. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32664433/5392118) is the good solution. Hope it works.

Comment: yeah you need to use expandable listview in navigation drawer. for all that behaviour. navigationView don't have that much customization till you need to be hacky.

Comment: Thank Mr Pramod. I appreciate your help.