# how to use expandable menu's in NavigationView

Tags: android

I am working on Navigation view and it is working fine .But I want to extend the items on particular item of menu.

I have defined menu items like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
          android:title="Import" />
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
          android:title="Gallery" />
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
          android:title="Slideshow" />
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
          android:title="Tools" />
  </group>-->

<item android:title="ACADEMIC">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

            <item
                android:id="@+id/challengeZone"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Home Work" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/interviewSchedule"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Interview Schedule" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/mockTestSchedule"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="MockTest Schedule" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/classSchdule"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Class Schedule" />

        </group>>

    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="PROFILE">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="My Profile" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/calender"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="My Calender" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Settings" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Log Out" />
        </group>
        >
    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="COMMUNICATE">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </group>
        >
    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="ADMISSION INFO">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/feeDetails"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Fee Details" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/admissionDetails"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Admission Details" />

        </group>
        >


    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="COMMUNICATION">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/documents"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Documents" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/messages"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Messages" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/notice"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Notice" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/leaveIntimation"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Leave Intimation" />
        </group>
        >

    </menu>


</item>


<item android:title="HELPDESK">

    <menu>

        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/helpDesk"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="HelpDesk "></item>

        </group>>
    </menu>


</item>
```

But that just a normal view like this

[image]

But I want the view like below image , when user click on top menu item an expandable menu open and hide when i click again. Please let me know how can I achieve this

[image]

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419446/adding-expandablelistview-to-navigationview

Comment: thank you , is this a working link , did you  tried it yourself ?

Comment: open the link and try out the solution given...i haven't tried...

Comment: Ohkay , working on it , thank you anyway

Comment: I was able to do the samething using expandable list view in android

Comment: would you please let me know how exactly did you perform this ?

Comment: I checked and it is working