# Collapsible item in navigation drawer with expandablelistview implementation

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I'm using android NavigationView I want after location touched from user expand something like a submenu and display the current location of user. Location is not my problem, my real problem is that I don't know how to implement ExpandableListView inside drawer for this simple example. Maybe you could suggest me an informative step by step tutorial for this one since I'm new android developer and I want to learn more.

Here is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/location" android:icon="@drawable/mylocation" android:title="@string/My_Location"  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
</group>

<item android:title="@string/action_settings">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item android:id="@+id/profile" android:icon="@drawable/settings"
                android:title="@string/Edit_Profile" android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />
            <item android:id="@+id/logout" android:icon="@drawable/logout"
                android:title="@string/Log_Out"  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

```
   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == R.id.location) { 
        //todo 
   }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to expand/collapse settings item?

Comment: no, with location item

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding expandableListView to NavigationView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419446/adding-expandablelistview-to-navigationview)

Comment: You can try the above question or else you can go through this github repositry [here](https://github.com/msahakyan/expandable-navigation-drawer)

Comment: Thank you guys! i check this repository to take a first look and then i try with my project