# Adding expandableListView to NavigationView using Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have gone through this soultions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419446/adding-expandablelistview-to-navigationview?answertab=votes#tab-top). But I'm not able to convert this java code to C# code as I'm using Xamarin. 
Anyone please help me out with C# code .

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a place where someone writes code for you. I would recommend to try to convert the code yourself and post it to Code Review if it does not work.

Comment: Yes it' is. Well I don't know why the community members can't answer the question , u can see my profile i have posted many question with error specs . Well u can left  this question in case as of I wanted conversion of code. Well I got the answer for my other questions from  other community .@RuslanBatdalov