# Android Navigation Drawer ExpandableListView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement SubMenu under Navigation Drawer Menu. There will be only One group menu. See the following image what I want to do. Currently I have only added the main menu from a xml menu list. How to add an ExpandableListView to a Menu as SubMenu to get the following type of interface.

[image]

Here the code I used to open/close navigation drawer and start activity on drawer menu click

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

//Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                Intent intent;
                int id = item.getItemId();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                if (id == R.id.favorites) {
                    Intent favoritesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Favorites.class);
                    startActivity(favoritesIntent);
                } else if (id == R.id.settings) {
                    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
                    startActivity(settingsIntent);
                }

                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        ImageView titleLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titleLogo);
        titleLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            }


      });
    .....

        @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

Here is the XML I used

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Here is the drawer.xml for menu list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/favorites"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/favorites"
            android:title="@string/favorites" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/services"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/services"
            android:title="@string/services" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            android:title="@string/settings" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to achieve above behavior to your NavigationDrawer you can follow below steps:

1) You have to add Expandable listview to your NavigationView.

2) Create Header View

3) Create Child View.

4) Extend BaseExpandableListAdapter

5) Set Adapter in MainActivity

There are few solutions available. You can follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) tutorial or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664433/7235049). For basic knowledge about creating Navigation drawer, you can go [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). I got helped by these tutorials and they are very easy to apply.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Download source code from here ([Navigation drawer with expandablelistview in android](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2017/07/navigation-drawer.html))

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.navigationdrawer;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Model_country> al_main = new ArrayList<>();
    ExpandableListView ev_list;
    CountryAdapter obj_adapter;
    String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    HomeFragment fragment;
    TextView tv_name;
    RelativeLayout rl_menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fn_data();
        init();

    }

    private void init() {

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ev_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ev_menu);
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        rl_menu = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_menu);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        obj_adapter = new CountryAdapter(MainActivity.this, al_main);
        ev_list.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        ev_list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });

        setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ev_list);

        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", al_main.get(0).getStr_country());
        bundle.putString("des", al_main.get(0).getAl_state().get(0).getStr_description());
        bundle.putString("dish", al_main.get(0).getAl_state().get(0).getStr_name());
        bundle.putString("image", al_main.get(0).getAl_state().get(0).getStr_image());
        tv_name.setText(al_main.get(0).getStr_country());

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "HomeFragment").addToBackStack("null").commit();


        rl_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                    || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            listView);
                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
       /* if (height < 10)
            height = 200;*/
        params.height = height;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }

    private void fn_data() {

        String str_data = loadJSONFromAsset();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject_country = new JSONObject(str_data);
            JSONArray jsonArray_country = jsonObject_country.getJSONArray("country");
            al_main = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_country.length(); i++) {
                Model_country obj_country = new Model_country();
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_country.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray jsonArray_dishes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dishes");
                ArrayList<Model_Dish> al_dishes = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray_dishes.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject_dishes = jsonArray_dishes.getJSONObject(j);
                    Model_Dish obj_dish = new Model_Dish();
                    obj_dish.setStr_name(jsonObject_dishes.getString("dishname"));
                    obj_dish.setStr_description(jsonObject_dishes.getString("description"));
                    obj_dish.setStr_image(jsonObject_dishes.getString("image"));
                    al_dishes.add(obj_dish);
                }

                obj_country.setAl_state(al_dishes);
                obj_country.setStr_country(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                al_main.add(obj_country);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ExpandableListView expandableListView) {
        CountryAdapter adapter = (CountryAdapter) expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = expandableListView.getPaddingTop() + expandableListView.getPaddingBottom();
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = adapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, expandableListView);
            groupItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = adapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null, expandableListView);
                    listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    listItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec
                            .makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = expandableListView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight + expandableListView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getGroupCount() - 1);

        if (height < 10)
            height = 100;
        params.height = height;
        expandableListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        expandableListView.requestLayout();
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("dishes.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Json response " + json);
        return json;

    }

    public void fn_selectedPosition(int group, int child) {

        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", al_main.get(group).getStr_country());
        bundle.putString("des", al_main.get(group).getAl_state().get(child).getStr_description());
        bundle.putString("dish", al_main.get(group).getAl_state().get(child).getStr_name());
        bundle.putString("image", al_main.get(group).getAl_state().get(child).getStr_image());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "HomeFragment").addToBackStack("null").commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

        tv_name.setText(al_main.get(group).getStr_country());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**CountryAdapter.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.navigationdrawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by deepshikha on 12/7/17.
 */

public class CountryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model_country> al_country;

    public CountryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_country> al_country) {
        this.context = context;
        this.al_country = al_country;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return al_country.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return al_country.get(i).getAl_state().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return al_country.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return al_country.get(i).getAl_state().get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view==null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_header, null);
        }
        TextView tv_state = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_state.setText(al_country.get(i).getStr_country());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view==null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_childview, null);
        }

        TextView tv_state = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

        tv_state.setText(al_country.get(i).getAl_state().get(i1).getStr_name());
        tv_state.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity)context).fn_selectedPosition(i,i1);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to integrate expandable list view with android built in drawer menu.
so you can use an expandable list view for entire drawer menu and not use a menu.xml file. but a trick you can do is to calculate height of each group when it's expanded and set the height at run time.
so assuming you follow all steps of @tahsinRupam you need to calculate height like below at run time:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if (expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i)){
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    expandableListView.setLayoutParams(params);
                } else {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 130 + any_number_of_child_items_you_have * 87);
                    expandableListView.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```