# ExpandableListView change drawable state_expanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-drawable, expandablelistadapter

I got a problem on my `ExpandableListAdapter`. I used a custom image as the `indicator`, because I wanted to position it to the right and not to the left of the menu item. I also need to hide the `indicator` on some items.

My drawable looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_expanded="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" />
</selector>
```

So I make use of the `state_expanded` of `Android`.

My `DrawerLayout` has this `LinearLayout` in it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_shadow">
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hide the normal `groupIndicator` manually to add the custom `Drawable` later in code.

My `ExpandableListAdapter` seems to be correct:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    ...

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_expanded };
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET //1
    };

    ...

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MOMenuItem headerTitle = (MOMenuItem) getGroup(groupPosition);

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, parent, false);
        convertView = linLayout;

        View indicator = convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator_image);

        if (groupPosition == 1) {
            Log.d("GetGroupView", "Called!");
        }

        if (indicator != null) {
            ImageView indicatorImage = (ImageView) indicator;
            if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0) {
                indicatorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (groupPosition == 1) {
                    Log.d("IsExpanded is", "" + isExpanded);
                }
                indicatorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int stateSetIndex = (isExpanded ? 1 : 0);
                if (groupPosition == 1) {
                    Log.d("State Index", "" + stateSetIndex);
                }
                Drawable drawable = indicatorImage.getDrawable();
                drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
            }
        }

        ...

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `indicator` doesn't get updated. However, the output of the `Log`-Statements for the item at index 1, when opened is:

1. GetGroupView: Called!
2. IsExpanded is: true
3. State Index: 1

The `indicator` stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research and trial and error I did not find a way to make it work with states. However, I used the images itself like the following:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MOMenuItem headerTitle = (MOMenuItem) getGroup(groupPosition);

    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, parent, false);
    convertView = linLayout;

    View indicator = convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator_image);

    if (indicator != null) {
        ImageView indicatorImage = (ImageView) indicator;
        if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0) {
            indicatorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            indicatorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (isExpanded) {
                indicatorImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
            } else {
                indicatorImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Sadly, the cleaner solution with a drawable and a state wasn't working. I hope this will help others stumbling upon this question.

Comment: @Bikram Sure you need to have an image with that ID in your project. I had that in 2017. But Android has changed a lot, so I would say my answer is probably outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57369511/6117565 and in you model programmatically add icons to a specific list item.