# Adding a expandable menu Item in a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

so im new here and have a question.

I whant to add a expandable menu item in a Navigation Drawer. So I know that I can use an expandableListView for that, but I don't whant that everything is expandable. I whant it like the imige.

[example of some expandable items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STSGm.png)

I search everywhere in the net, but I have found only examples with expandableListView

so if you need some Code pleas let me know

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32419446/2999762 this might help you

Comment: Sorry this is with the expendableListView, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=hVJpWSalzbo

Here is some Tutorial vor a ListView with expandable submenu. So I adapted the code a bit for my use