# How to build Navigation Bars with Icon

Tags: java, android-studio, dropdown, sidebar, navigationbar

I want to make side bars like this (some of required dropdown) and with icon , I used android studio template layout but I not find yet how to add subitem to dropdown, and I try to use expandable list, but not find yet how to add icon,
the output hope like this, any idea?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419446/adding-expandablelistview-to-navigationview , it will help you.

Comment: thanks saif! hope its help!!

Comment: thanks @PrateekBhardwaj hope its helps!!